# Make one table row disappear when clicking another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I actually want to do a couple of things and i can't find anything similar that is javascript and not jQuery.
[Updated fiddle with working code](https://jsfiddle.net/mpasd/hntexnjc/). Thanks to LuudJacobs.
I know, it's stupid.. It's just for practice, i'm new to this. It is also not finished.
So, what i want to do is:
- If "Primo Victoria" row is open, close it when "Attero Dominatus", or any other row is clicked/opened. But Show lyrics should be allowed to have as many instances open as the user wants.
- Make "Show Lyrics" text turn into "Hide Lyrics" when clicked.
I actually almost got this one, but instead of changing text, i made a new link...

```
document.getElementsByClassName("lyrics")[0].onclick = function () {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("showLyrics")[0];
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("lyrics")[0];
    if (x.style.display === "none" || x.style.display === "") {
      x.style.display = "table-row";
      y.innerHTML = '<a href="#" class="lyrics">Hide Lyrics</a>';
    }
    else {
      x.style.display = "none";
      y.innerHTML = '<a href="#" class="lyrics">Show Lyrics</a>'
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: this link will help you https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Comment: @aandis eehhhh.... what? why? explain...

Comment: I have read that using jQuery makes programming with js a lot easier, but it is also really big and takes more time to load. So i am conflicted as to whether i should learn it or not. For the time being i want to understand js completely before moving on to any frameworks.

Comment: @mpasd That's probably the right way of doing it. jQuery takes care of a lot of inconsistencies between browsers and adds some quality of life features. However, the need for these features has diminished somewhat over the last couple of years. I started out using jQuery, and learned JS from there. Now I try not to use any large frameworks if not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the style of the table row directly, it's better to use classes and toggle those instead. That way it's easier to target 'expanded' table rows. Your code could look something like this:

```
/* CSS */
.showLyrics{
  display: none; /* hide table row by default */
}
.showLyrics.visible{
  display: table-row; /* show the table row */
}
```

Now you can use Javascript to toggle between classes:

```
//Javascript
document.getElementsByClassName("lyrics")[0].onclick = function(){
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("showLyrics")[0];

  //check if the row already has a .visible class
  if(x.classList.contains('visible')){

    //hide the row if it's already visible
    x.classList.remove('visible');

    /* other stuff you want to do on hiding a table row */

  }else{

    //hide all rows which are visible (have class .visible)
    var visibleRows = document.querySelectorAll('.visible'),
        i, l = visibleRows.length;

    for(i = 0; i < l; ++i){
      visibleRows[i].classList.remove('visible');
    }

    //show the row
    x.classList.add('visible');

    /* other stuff you want to do on showing a table row */

  }
}
```

Alternatively you can use `x.classList.toggle('visible');` Read up on `.classList` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

As a sidenote: when I looked into your fiddle, I layed my eyes upon this: `<tr class="tableEntry1, hover">`. I'm pretty sure you meant `<tr class="tableEntry1 hover">`. Note: no comma. Classes should be separated by a space, not a comma.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to work... I am getting no errors in the console, nothing happens when i click now. I might be doing something wrong. Can you provide a working example please?

Comment: @mpasd what errors do you get? Can you add _your_ current code to a fiddle or something like that?

Comment: As i said, no errors. The code works, just not the way it is supposed to work. Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpasd/azw1xj1k/ ... I will also change the link in the original post. When i click on the first table row with the second one open, it does close, but it doesn't open the new one...

Comment: @mpasd my bad: after `else` first a class was added, and then it looked up everything with that class to remove it again. Changed these parts around, should be working now.

Comment: That answers my first question. Thank you. Could you also help me with changing text inside the link. When clicked Show Lyrics should change to Hide Lyrics, but all i managed to do is make a new link using innerHTML... How do i access and change the text inside an <a> tag...

Comment: @mpasd: `document.querySelector('a').innerHTML = 'new link text';` is one way of doing it

Comment: That is kinda what i am looking for, and thank you for sticking with me so far. But how can i select different links with same class without making extra classes? Use my fiddle as an example, i want to apply it to all links with "Show Lyrics" text. What would be the best way?

Comment: Nevermind, i got it working with textContent. But feel free to suggest a better way to do it, if there is one. And thanks again!